# Rails 3: Form Submission - Setting Textfield as :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple page with one textfield and a submit button. I want a user to be able to enter a string, and have the submit button direct the user to a certain page, where the textfield is in the URL as the :id.

For example, if the user enters "test", clicking submit should send him to "/controller/action/test".

Is this possible? I tried:

```
<%= form_tag :controller => "myController", :action => "myAction", :id => :textFieldName do %> ...
```

but that does not work. (I didn't suspect it would.)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use Javascript. In the simplest form

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  $(this).attr('action') = '/url/prefix/' + $(this).find('input#the_field').val();
  return true;
});
```

And then the handler should return and the form should submit to the new url.

Note that you should also validate/normalize the field's content.

Answer (score 0):

You could try...

Don't set the ID of the form tag. Instead, take the value of the text field, from the `params` hash as your indication of where to redirect to.

i.e., in the view...

```
<% text_field_tag :id => "test_value" ... %>
```

and in the controller...

```
redirect_to "/action/" + params[:test_value]
```